# How do I resolve the "-bash: aws: command not found" awscli error?

Tags: python, aws-cli

I've installed the AWS CLI following [Install the AWS CLI version 1 on macOS Using pip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-pip).

```
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

However, when I attempt to run AWS CLI commands, I get the following error.

```
$ aws --version
-bash: aws: command not found
```

I've confirmed that the AWS CLI is installed.

```
$ pip list
Package              Version  
-------------------- ---------
awscli               1.16.279
```

Why is the `aws` command not found even though I've successfully installed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `~/.local/bin` directory to your path. For example:

```
# .bashprofile
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Source: [Add the AWS CLI version 1 Executable to Your macOS Command Line Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path)