# Aws command not found on Airflow, but work in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, aws-cli

I have in Airflow a BashOperator that executes an `aws s3 ls s3:/path` command. It works on the console but it doesn't works on Airflow, the error message is: `command not found` . Aws is correctly installed, the following URL explains how the PATH was set:
[How do I resolve the "-bash: aws: command not found" awscli error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203475/how-do-i-resolve-the-bash-aws-command-not-found-awscli-error)  and how it was installed: [Is it possible to install aws-cli package without root permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123740/is-it-possible-to-install-aws-cli-package-without-root-permission) .

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.209 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.0-58-generic botocore/1.19.49
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please help. How can I make this command (and any other in aws) work on Airflow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Airflow might be creating a non-interactive shell so you don't have direct access to the AWS binaries in the shell. Try running source ~/.bashrc or source .profile before executing the aws commands.

Comment: are you running airlfow in docker perhaps?

Comment: @chorbs  It is not runnning in docker , is in a ubuntu

Comment: add your operator instantiation code; show output of `which path` in the terminal immediately before running `airflow test ...` for the task in the same terminal.  the env should propagate, unless you provide env explicitly in bash op.